# In Python, is there any way to have variables automatically placed into a list?

Tags: python, list, automation

With the following preface:

```
insane_numbers = [1,5,10,50,100,500,1000]
crazy_numbers = []
```

Suppose I defined a "crazy number" as any number, excluding insane numbers, that, when subtracted from the next highest insane number, forms its own insane number. For example, 4 is a crazy number because when subtracted from 5, the next highest insane number, the result is 1, another insane number.

```
if ((next_biggest_number - num)) in insane_numbers:
    crazy_numbers.append(num)
```

However, I want, if possible, for the program to recognize immediately upon my declaration of a variable whether or not it is a crazy number. I don't want to have an if statement after the declaration of every integer. I want `crazy_numbers.append()` to occur instantaneously upon my declaration of an integer without having to manually populate `crazy_numbers` through conditionals.

How can one do this in Python?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "declaration of an integer"? Do you mean the assignment of any integer value to any variable? Or do you mean assignment of an integer to a specific variable (or for example, adding it to some list)?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want the assignment `a = 4` to have the side-effect of performing `crazy_numbers.append(a)`. I don't  know of *any* programming language that will do that declaratively. You could conceivably write a class that would do that, but the implementation would  still have to "manually populate crazy_numbers through conditionals".

Comment: What you are suggesting is adding a side effect to a variable assignment, which I don't think is supported by the language. It will need to be done with inspection checking the local variables but will still require you to call something. Perhaps just wrap a function around `int()` and use that upon assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Define an automatically added function and call it continuously:

```
>>> crazy_numbers = []
>>> def is_crazy_number(integer):
...     return True
...
>>> def try_append_crazy_number(integer):
...     if is_crazy_number(integer):
...         crazy_numbers.append(integer)
...
>>> try_append_crazy_number(1)
>>> try_append_crazy_number(2)
>>> try_append_crazy_number(3)
>>> crazy_numbers
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to add it automatically through the assignment statement, consider using `property`:

```
>>> class CrazyNumberAppender:
...     def _try_append(self, integer):
...         if is_crazy_number(integer):
...             crazy_numbers.append(integer)
...     number = property(fset=_try_append)
...
>>> appender = CrazyNumberAppender()
>>> appender.number = 10
>>> appender.number = 15
>>> crazy_numbers
[1, 2, 3, 10, 15]
```